# change navigation alignment in center

Tags: html, css, navigation

i am try to change alignment of navigation in center..
in fixed position..
i am also try "<center>" tag in html and "text-align: center;" in css but not work..
it's jsfiddle link -> http://jsfiddle.net/5FvKT/ 
it's **CSS**

```
html,body {
    margin: 0px;padding-top:25px;
}
#nav-bar {
    position: fixed;top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
}
#nav {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 45px;
}
#nav > li {
    display: inline-block;width: 15em;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px}
ul li a{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalized;
    height: 35px;
    color:#222;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:48px;
}
ul li a:hover, ul li a.active{
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:3px solid #800000;
    color:#800000
}
```

and **HTML** is

```
<div id="nav-bar"> 
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Conference</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Magazine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Market</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FvKT/2/)).

that's what i modified:

```
#nav {text-align:center;}
#nav > li { display: inline-block;}
ul li{display:inline-block;}
```

if you don't want `#nav` to be fixed on 1200 width, just give it `width:100%;`

hope that helps.